# Rails 5.1: How do I fire a callback when an associated record changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have two models `User` and `PostalAddress`. For various reasons, I want to store latitude and longitude on `User` instead of `PostalAddress`. If the postal address changes, I want the coordinates to update.

```rb
class PostalAddress < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    # ...
    end
```

I believe I want to do something like this:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :postal_address, dependent: :destroy, required: true

    before_save :update_coords, if: :will_save_change_to_postal_address?
```

But it fails with the error:

```
NoMethodError:  undefined method `will_save_change_to_postal_address?'
```

However, it works for attributes that actually belong to `User`:

```rb
before_save :update_coords, if: :will_save_change_to_email_address?
```

I have also learned about `:after_add` and `:before_add` callbacks but I understand that they only work for `has_many` collections.

How do I fire a callback when an associated record changes?

Answer (score 2):

Do the before_save in the PostalAddress model and call the method to update the longitude and latitude on the User.

```rb
class PostalAddress < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  before_save :update_coords, if: :will_save_change_to_postal_address?
  # ...

  private

  def update_coords
    self.user.update_coordinates
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

> If the postal address changes, I want the coordinates to update.

```
class PostalAddress < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :update_coords

  def update_coords
    # here you can check specific attributes changes if required, else it will call every time PostalAddress changes 
    user.update(lat: calculated_value1, long: calculated_value2)
  end
end
```

Comment: The PostalAddress model shouldn't be responsible for actually updating the user: `user.update(lat: calculated_value1, long: calculated_value2)` Or am I misunderstanding SRP?